# Generating $U[0,1]$ from 3 $U[a,b]$ of unknown $a$ and $b$

Tags: random-variables

I received this interesting question from my friend.

Suppose we have 3 random number generators, each generates value from the uniform distribution on the interval $[a, b]$. Can we construct random number generator that generate uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ given that $a$ and $b$ is unknown?

Comment: You can even do it with one. It appears something is missing in the question.

Comment: @LordSoth How would you do it with one generator, without knowing $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The generators produce three numbers; order them as $x\ge y\ge z $ and define $$t=\frac{x-y}{x-z}$$
The quantity $t$ is  uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Sketch of proof. The probability density of the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $6$ times the Lebesgue measure restricted to the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,1,1)$. The probability that $t$ lies in the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ is $6$ times the volume of the tetrahedron with   vertices  $(0,0,0)$, $(1,\alpha, 0)$, $(1,\beta,0)$, $(1,1,1)$. The volume of the latter tetrahedron is 
$$\frac16\begin{vmatrix} 1 & \alpha & 0 \\ 1 & \beta & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}
=\frac{\beta-\alpha}6
$$